# Array to XML in Php (using DOM)

Tags: php, xml, arrays, dom

i just have a php array with number that i've "explode" to separate itens,

```
$arr = array($_POST["fname"]);
```

`$arr = explode(',', $_POST['fname']);`

`$parentesis;`

`$parentesis2;`

`for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i+=2){`

```
    `$parentesis = substr($arr[$i], 1);`


    `$parentesis2 = substr($arr[$i+1], 0,-1);`
```

actually arays are `$arr[0] = 435567899`, `$arr[1] = -78904452`, `$arr[2] = 345688` , `$arr[3] = -3456778`

and i need put this "numbers" in xml,

something like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

`<rotas>`

`<routa>`

```
<p x="4060092" y="-870872498" />

<p x="4062229178" y="-865310669" />
```

`</routa>`

`</rotas>`

so postion zero and one in a line, the next two postions in other, etc..

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have it. I would just build an XML string inside your loop, like so:

```
$routa = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr);){
  $routa .= '<p x="' . $arr[++$i] . '" y="' . $arr[++$i] . '" />';
}
```

Keep in mind this assumes matching pairs in your array. Just stuff `$routa` in your XML schema when your ready to output.

Comment: While this _works_ you probably shouldn't be manually constructing the XML like that, as it loses some of flexibility you can get by using a real XML parser/builder

Comment: @Jaime agreed for a larger XML document. From the OP, the XML seemed trivial and my answer simply modifies existing code.

Comment: hi, when i explode the original POST this put each element in one postition of the array $arr, it's ok? cause i need the first two in a line the next two one other, etc...
my point is do something like this: http://tinypaste.com/d2811 
offcourse without the database...